# Send a rocket against orbit around the sun

Tags: orbit

I presume it's a bit simplified, but ...

What if we launch a rocket, the same speed but opposite direction of the orbit of our planet around the sun.

Will that rocket fall into the sun?

Comment: Do you mean a speed of 30 km/s in the opposite direction, or a speed of 0?

Answer (score 9):

In a simplified sense, yes.

Relative to the sun, the Earth moves at approximately 30 km/s.  So if we could launch a rocket in the opposite direction of Earth's rotation at 30 km/s, it would have a velocity of 0 relative to the Sun, and would be accelerated directly towards it by gravity from the Sun ("falling towards it").

This assumes that a rocket could be accelerated to 30 km/s before leaving Earth's orbit however.  [See this answer to a previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10193/15841) if you want to see the upper speed limits on systems that we can launch.  The fastest system we've launched has been New Horizons at 16.26 km/s.

Comment: Thanks.  And I wasn't really looking for a practical way, just the principle of it.

Comment: The principle is: Your rocket is de-orbiting the sun and free from any forces but the sun gravity it ill fall on it

Comment: Note through smart  trajectory and gravity assists, you could send a rocket into a (very elongated) solar retrograde orbit. It would first involve launching it somewhere near Pluto's orbit, possibly a help from Jupiter in turning more towards retrograde, then performing a burn to accelerate in the solar-retrograde direction (and possibly catching some gravity assists to increase that speed). The fundamental question here though is WHAT FOR?