# What is the fastest we could travel in space, or have ever traveled in space?

Tags: spacecraft, observation, travel, record, velocity

What is the fastest vehicle currently in space? With our current technology, at what point does physics start to restrict our speed in space?

Comment: Is there any kind of meta policy on questions whose answers will change over relatively short timescales?  https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10193/11262 is relevant to all-time records, but the "currently" seems to make this not-a-duplicate.

Comment: Your main question is still somewhat confusing

Comment: @Conelisinspace the title contains bot past and future tense although the grammar my not be perfect.

Comment: There is a chance that this describes the fastest ever velocity of a spacecraft (in a sense) close to the Earth and measured relative to the Earth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob#Propulsion_of_steel_plate_cap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want speed, look for mass. Things closest to the Sun will tend to be moving the fastest.

For example the [Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESSENGER) spacecraft reached **almost 63 km/s** when in an elliptical orbit who's perihelion matched Mercury's position.

In the 2nd plot you can see the red line (speed wrt Mercury) drops to a very low value in 2011, that's when it entered into orbit around Mercury.

I'm now looking for data for [Mariner-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_10).

I have [estimated that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348854/83380) *In the future* the [Parker Solar Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) will reach **about 195 km/s** as it passes within a few million km of the Sun!

Data below from JPL's [Horizions](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The only absolute limit imposed by physics is the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light), but with our current technology -- reaction engines based on [Newton's laws of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) -- we're limited by practical engineering issues and [Tsiolkovsky's rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) to speeds on the order of 1/10000 of the speed of light.

Comment: "Do I contradict myself? Very well, then I contradict myself, I am large, I contain multitudes." - Walt Whitman

Comment: The 17 km/s is the fastest *radial velocity* with respect to the Sun? Anything in a heliocentric orbit near Earth's is moving like ~30 km/s, just not *away* from the Sun.

Comment: I think a much better measure of this sort of records would be the specific orbital energy; if we could turn Voyager 2 around (say, by a flyby of some interstellar planet) and get it near Earth, it would blow all the 30km/s vessels out of the vacuum. And crashing it into the Sun would beat all the records. Current 17km/s is so unimpressive only because most of its orbital energy is in the potential energy. IIRC New Horizons  is currently faster - but by the time it reaches where Voyager 2 is now, it will be much slower.

Comment: @SF. [agreed](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28421/what-is-the-fastest-can-we-or-have-ever-traveled-in-space#comment85691_28429). The Voyagers and New Horizons have very high $C_3$.

Comment: Good points, I’ll delete the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's useful to note  that the **whole concept of fastest velocity in space is some confusing**.

For example - altough [**Parker Solar Probe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) will be the fastest spacecraft even made, **it will not have enough velocity to ever reach Mars** from it's trajectory. Paradox?

Spacecraft are not like race cars on track where the fastest wins.

The better analogy are cars at a road in mountain region. The vehicle in a valley can have big velocity 120 km/h, but it's not enough to drive at the top of 1-km-high mountain by inertia only. Opposite, another car at the mountain's top can drive slowly 20 km/h, but it's total energy (kinetic + potential) is higher that the energy of the first car in the valley. If we drive the second car down from 1-km mountain without breaking, its final velocity will be insane.

It's the same for spacecraft. The total energy (kinetic + potential) of a spacecraft tells us where it can fly and where can not, and how much time we need to reach our target.

Comment: Thus the concept of C3 , or "excess v^2 above escape velocity". ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26074/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26090/12102)) Anything bound to the Sun has a negative $C_3$ , anything with escape velocity has positive $C_3$ . Once you know a spacecraft's heliocentric $C_3$, you can get the current velocity $v$ from the current distance from the Sun $r$ from $v^2 = C_3 + 2mμ/r$.

Comment: ...oops, that's $v^2 = C_3 + 2 \mu / r$ the $m \mu$ is a typo

Comment: let me know when it does

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the New Horizons spacecraft was the fastest ever space probe launched into space with a speed of 16.26km/s and there are other type of speed records held by Helios an Juno spacecrafts.

The below link is worth checking

http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2016/7/nasa%E2%80%99s-juno-probe-recognised-by-guinness-world-records-as-fastest-ever-spacecraft