# Are there any accurate velocity plots of all spacecraft that achieved escape velocity from the solar system? (Pioneers, Voyagers, & New Horizons)

Tags: spacecraft, voyager, new-horizons, escape-velocity, pioneer

The answer to [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10371/38024) question provides a seemingly accurate plot of the velocity of Voyager 2 over distance along with the heliocentric escape velocity.

Are there similar graphs for the other 4 spacecraft (Pioneer 10, Pioneer 11, Voyager 1, New Horizons) that are accurate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wikimedia has the following graph for the heliocentric velocities of both Pioneer probes:
([SVG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Pioneer_speed_and_distance_from_Sun.svg))

As far as I can tell it's accurate, since it clearly shows the velocity change of Pioneer 10 during its Jupiter flyby on new year 1974, and Pioneer 11's two flybys of Jupiter on new year 1975 and Saturn in 1979.

[image: Pioneer 10 and 11 velocity]

And New Horizons: [(SVG)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/New_Horizons_Speed_and_distance_from_Sun.svg)

([This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10193/8693) also has one.)

[image: New Horizon velocity]

And both Voyagers: ([SVG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Voyager_speed_and_distance_from_Sun.svg))

[image: voyager velocities]